# Technique for following a program with forks and threads

Tags: c, process, pthreads, fork

I'm having an exam in OS and they usually ask question like: what possible outputs the following program can have:

```
void* func1(void* param){
    printf("A");
    return 0;
}
void* func2(void* param){
    printf("B");
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    pthread_t th;
    if(fork() > 0){
        pthread_create(&th, NULL, func1, NULL);
        wait(NULL);
    } else{
        close(1);
        open("file.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
        pthread_create(&th, NULL, func2, NULL);
    }
    printf("C");
    pthread_join(th,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

It a bit sad that today, the grades are determine if you can follow a program but nevertheless, I'm looking for a technique of what would be the best way to follow all the routes in that program. Should I draw a process/threads tree? Some other diagram? What technique will make it easier to follow such programs?

Comment: Start with methods which you know.

Comment: This specific code is quite straightforward. No multilevel forks, each process only spawning one extra thread. So here, you can basically analyze each process by itself, and then interleave their outputs in every possible combination.

Comment: just read the code and consider possible orders of execution it can have. If you want add some `usleep` in different locations with different duration to check you are right

Comment: I gave a very basic example so if someone has a technique, he could preform on it. Usually they ask much harder flows. If this question does not meet with SO rules, please let me know.

Comment: well, a *general* technique would be a process tree, because it is the natural structure of what it is.